# How to select duplicate columns data from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have table like :

```
col1  col2   col3  col4  col5
test1   1     13    15    1
test2   1     13    15    4
test3   2     7      3    5
test4   3     11    14    18
test5   3     11    14    8
test6   3     11    14    11
```

Want select `col1,col2,col3,col4` data where `col2,col3,col4` are duplicates 
for example it must be :

```
col1  col2   col3  col4 
test1   1     13    15    
test2   1     13    15  
test4   3     11    14  
test5   3     11    14
test6   3     11    14
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming SQL-Server >= 2005 you can use [`COUNT(*) OVER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col2, col3, col4)
    FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM CTE WHERE cnt > 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6bb65/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col1 <> t.col1) and
      exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col1 <> t.col1) and
      exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.col3 = t.col3 and t2.col1 <> t.col1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Join can work

```
select m1.col1,m1.col2,m1.col3,m1.col4 from Mytable m1
join Mytable m2
on m1.col2 =m2.col2
and m1.col3=m2.col3
and m1.col4 =m2.col4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for that:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table

MINUS

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM your_table
```

**EDIT:** sorry this works only for complete duplicates. If you want to exclude the first column, you can use

```
SELECT col2,col3,col4 FROM your_table

MINUS

SELECT DISTINCT col2,col3,col4 FROM your_table
```

and afterwards make a `join` with the table itself (`ON` its primary keys).